# How do i make multiple images upload in django (2.2) in one form with two data methods?

Tags: python, django

How do I make a multiple images upload to database in django?
I have 2 models: Ads, Images

models.py

```
class Ads(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=85, blank=False)

class Images(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ads, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='')
    thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
class CreateAd(CreateView):
    model = Ads
    form_class = CreateAdForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

forms.py

```
class CreateAdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ads
        fields = ('title',)

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('image', )
```